# How to create java window without a GUI

Tags: java

I have been given an assignment for uni to make a chess game without using a GUI(swing or Java FX)

I have made the game using the AWT Canvas Class. However, I cannot figure out how to actually make a java window or frame for the game to run in without using a GUI?

Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need some kind of an interface. You could use the console for human/pc interchange. `System.out` and `System.in`.

Comment: Using AWT was the wrong choice as well. I guess the assignment was asking for a command line program.

Comment: you should make something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96_Mxpbx7VQ